# Display/hiding bottom nav bar - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a `UITableViewController` and a `TabBar` inside of the `TableView` and I want to be able to display that `TabBar` at the bottom of the IPhone screen and not at the bottom of the `Table Cells`  So The `TabBar` will always remain fixed to the screen but at the bottom.

Not sure how I can accomplish this within a `Table View Controller`?

The `TabBar` is a navigation bar to be more exact.  To leave the table and go to different `controllers`.

Okay so I just realized I was just pulling a `TabBar` into the controller.  So I went to the `Navigation Controller` and set the bottom bar in.  So that takes me to my next question, how do I display that button bar in certain `view controllers` and not show it in others.

Comment: What is the tab bar supposed to represent? Is it supposed to allow you to leave the view controller and go to another one? It sounds like you are not using tab bars correctly.

Comment: Just to make it clear, you are using a `UINavigationBar`, right?

Comment: @guilherme i just updated my question

Comment: When you resolve an issue and you have a new question, please accept the answer and start a new question.

Comment: But you didn't make it any clearer. You're not supposed to use two controllers that way. A `UITabBarController` has to be the main one, then you add a `UITableViewController` on top of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `UITabBar` is not correct for what you are trying to accomplish. The standard use of a `UITabBar` is in the context of a `UITabBarController`.

[`UITabBarController` doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Here is a sample use of tab bars.

1) Create a `UITabBarController` and set it as the `rootViewController` of your `window` in your `AppDelegate`.

2) Assign the `viewControllers` property of the tab bar controller to be an array of the view controllers you want to be able to switch between (which you must also create).

3) You will need to do some additional research if you want to style the different aspects of the tab bar. Some things are styled by accessing the `tabBar` property of the `UITabBarController` directly. Other things (like individual tab icons and titles) are set by using the `tabBarItem` property of each view controller.

4) If you want to encapsulate all of this logic into one place and potentially change some of the default logic, subclass `UITabBarController`.

edit: your question has changed a bit and I'm not sure this answer is valid anymore. That said, it sounds like you are also misusing the `UINavigationBar`as this is not really its intended purpose (perhaps you meant to use a `UIToolBar`?)

Comment: I just updated my question

Answer (score 0):

The problem of your code design is that you are using UITableViewController. It's view is UITableView and everything that you'll add as a subview will scroll with contents.

Quick and hack-free solution is to use:

- UIViewController
- Add UITableView to as a subview
- add you TabBar (as I understood this is UINavigationBar) as a subview to your viewcontroller.view, but not to the tableview.
  In such way your TabBar will always be placed above your UITableView, and will not scroll.